# Dojo mobile and callback in dojox.mobile.ListItem

Tags: javascript, mobile, dojo

I'm a dojo newbie and have encountered this problem in mobile version: I try to use callback with javascript function, but it wont work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
function My_function(){
    alert("Hello");
}
</script>

<div id="homepage_view" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">

  <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading">Mobile....</h1>

  <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList">
    <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
        data-dojo-props='moveTo:"whereIam_view",
                         transition:"slide",
                         callback:"My_function()",
                         '>sth....</li>
    <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
        data-dojo-props='moveTo:"places_aroud_me_view",
                         transition:"slide"'>sth else....</li>
    <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem"
        data-dojo-props='moveTo:"places_in_koszalin_view",
                         transition:"slide"'>sth even more else....</li>                         
  </ul>

</div>
```

Thanx for help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use reference instead of function name string.
Instead of:

```
function My_function(){
alert("Hello");
}
```

Use:

```
functionName = function My_function(){
alert("Hello");
}
```

And then inside the prop

```
 data-dojo-props='moveTo:"whereIam_view",
                         transition:"slide",
                         callback:functionName,
                         '>sth....</li>
```

Remember! Without the quotes around the functionName