# Can't find Dojo IconMenuItem callback example. (Defined by dojox/mobile/_ItemBase)

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I can't find Dojo IconMenuItem callback example. (Defined by dojox/mobile/_ItemBase)

> callback
>
> Defined by dojox/mobile/_ItemBase
>
> A callback function that is called when the transition has been finished. A function reference, or name of a function in context.

I try to call a function after the transition is called.

I tried to find an example how to set the callback function.
I also need to find an example of giving the function a context (parameters).

Like this:
on(iconJs, "click", lang                                    .hitch({"context":{"currentSchool":schools[i].id}}, function(){getKlassen("fillKlastoevoegenView", this.context);}));

This is what I tried (for html part)

```
     <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.IconMenuItem" data-dojo-props="label: 'Scholen', transition:'slide', url:'views/klappr/overviewSchool.html', urlTarget:'overviewSchool' callback : 'overviewSchoolController.show()';" ></li>
```

I also need to do it programmatically like this

```
                         iconJs =new dojox.mobile.IconItem({label:'', deletable: false, icon:'images/Tile_Toevoegen.png', transition:'slide', class:'klasIcon', url:'views/klappr/addKlas.html', urlTarget:'addKlas', callback : 'overviewSchoolController.show();'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ItemBase is the base class for several Dojo widgets, including dojox.mobile.ListItem (which I believe is the most common of all of them).

So, for what you are looking for, here you'll find how to do the simplest example: [Dojo mobile and callback in dojox.mobile.ListItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008629/dojo-mobile-and-callback-in-dojox-mobile-listitem)

Also, for the programatic sample, this should help: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.dojo.user/54040 specially this one: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.dojo.user/54117